# How to drop specific rows a DataFrame to generate a nested JSON

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am currently working on a d3 treemap which require a nested json as a entry, I succeded in organizing my df and generating the json but some of my treemap rectangle are 30x bigger than other so I decided to drop the rows that generate this rectangle.

My function `dropSmall()` iterate in my columns and my rows to verify for each groupby if the sum is 30x smaller than the max sum 
I am struggling with updating the df either using a drop or affecting the value that match 
Here is my code:

```py
def dropSmall(df):
    list = []
    for i in df.columns: #b, c, z ..
        if i != 'valeur' and i!='unite':
            list.append(i)
            # iterating on rows
            for j in range(df.groupby(list).sum().shape[0]): 
                myMax = df.groupby(list).sum().iloc[:, 0].max() / 30
                myJ = df.groupby(list).sum().iloc[:, 0][j]
                myDf = df.groupby(list).sum().iloc[:, 0]
                if myJ <= myMax:
                    df = df[myDf['value']>=  myMax]
```

and my groupby look like this

```
          name          b   c   z   l   sL  value       unit
3099    Myindicator     1   1   3   NA  NA  129.74      kg
3100                                    1   44929.74    kg
3101                                    2   5174.74     kg
3110                    3   1   3   1   NA  2497.66     kg
3156                                2   NA  29.43       kg
3222                                3   NA  304.81      kg
```

For the example of the firt row when b=1 c=1 z=3 l=NA I want to verify while iterating on the 3 sL that the value of the sL is > 30x the max of this sum and for this case drop the row when value = 129

My function verify the condition but I don't know how to drop the row from  my initial df not `df.groupby('list').sum()`

Example of the ungrouped df for the first row

```
        name        Continent  Region   Country   State   City    Borough  Value       Unit
1000    Myindicator     1        1        3        1      1         1      53.86      kg
```

[EDIT FROM HERE]

My cutoff multiplier here is 2
There is a max for each hierarchy

```
                                            Value
name        Continent Region Country State       
Myindicator 1         1      1       7         50[MAX]
                                     8         30 
                             2       5         70[MAX]
                                     6         30 *
                             3       1         50[MAX]
                             4       5        200[MAX]
                                     6        150 
                             5       1        300[MAX]
                                     6        160
                                     7        100*
                                     8         50*
                                     9         50*
                      2      4       9        100[MAX]
                                     10        40 *
                             5       3         80[MAX]
                                     11        20 *
                             6       2         10[MAX]
                      3      7       12       100[MAX]
```

In this example you won't drop region 2  country  6    state   2   because it's the only row for this region>country>state and it's at the same time the max

Hope this is clearer

Comment: Are you able to share some of the ungrouped, original dataframe?

Comment: The original is approximately the same this is just the sum.
For example I want for the first group to drop only the first row not all the indicator with this parameter

Comment: So you want to drop it from the grouped data frame? Because your code above is trying to drop rows from the ungrouped frame where you do `df = df[myDF[“value”] >= myMax]`

Comment: I want to drop it from the ungrouped dataframe but only for the same parameter. I n example for the first row I want to drop all the rows that make this sum so all the rows where name= Myindicator, b=1, c=1, z=3,l=NA, sL=NA. And I cant to do it also for the oter columns that why the function need to be recursive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am not 100% clear on what your input looks like, or what you want back, but if I understand correctly I think the following would work.

**EDITED FROM HERE**

**EDIT2**: Added stars (`*`) to indicate which rows are getting dropped.

**EDIT3**: Changed function due to the way assignment and copies work with `pandas.DataFrame`

A function to do the process:

```
def drop_small(dfcop, cutoff_multiplier):
    # Create copy of dataframe so we don't alter the original
    df=dfcop.copy(deep=True)
    # Group on all columns except 'Value' and 'Unit'
    grp_cols = [i for i in df.columns if i not in ['Value', 'Unit']]
    groupers = [grp_cols[:i+1] for i in range(len(grp_cols))]
    print(groupers)
    #loop through all hierarchical groupings
    for grp in groupers:
        print(f"Grouping on {grp}")
        # Add a column with the group sums to the dataframe
        df['gsum'] = df.groupby(grp)['Value'].transform('sum')
        # Compute the max of the parent group - don't do this if we are grouping by a single field
        if len(grp) > 1:
            df['gmax'] = df.groupby(grp[:-1])['gsum'].transform(lambda x: max(x)/cutoff_multiplier)
        else:
            df['gmax'] = df.gsum.max()/cutoff_multiplier
        print("Grouped sums and cutoffs for this hierarchy:")
        print(df)
        # Drop all rows where the group sum is less than the cutoff mulitplier of the max
        idexs = df[df.gsum < df.gmax].index
        df = df[df.gsum >= df.gmax]
        print('Indexes dropped:')
        print(','.join([str(i) for i in idexs]))
        # Remove the group sum column
        df.drop(['gsum', 'gmax'], axis=1, inplace=True)
    return df
```

Here's how it works for the example table.

```
           name  Continent  Region  Country  State  Value Unit
0   Myindicator          1       1        3      1     50   kg
1   Myindicator          1       1        3      4     50   kg
2   Myindicator          1       1        2      5     20   kg
3   Myindicator          1       1        2      5     50   kg
4   Myindicator          1       1        2      6     30   kg
5   Myindicator          1       1        1      7     50   kg
6   Myindicator          1       1        1      8     20   kg
7   Myindicator          1       2        4      9     50   kg
8   Myindicator          1       2        4      9     50   kg
9   Myindicator          1       2        4     10     40   kg
10  Myindicator          1       2        5     11     20   kg
11  Myindicator          1       2        5      3     40   kg
12  Myindicator          1       2        5      3     40   kg
13  Myindicator          1       2        6      2     10   kg
14  Myindicator          1       3        7     12     50   kg
15  Myindicator          1       3        7     12     50   kg
16  Myindicator          1       3        8     14     15   kg
17  Myindicator          1       3        8     14     15   kg
18  Myindicator          1       3        8     13     15   kg
19  Myindicator          1       3        8     13      1   kg
20  Myindicator          1       4        9     15     10   kg
21  Myindicator          1       4        9     16     10   kg
```

Grouping on `['name']`
Grouped sums and cutoffs for this hierarchy:

```
           name  Continent  Region  Country  State  Value Unit  gsum  gmax
0   Myindicator          1       1        3      1     50   kg   686   343
1   Myindicator          1       1        3      4     50   kg   686   343
2   Myindicator          1       1        2      5     20   kg   686   343
3   Myindicator          1       1        2      5     50   kg   686   343
4   Myindicator          1       1        2      6     30   kg   686   343
5   Myindicator          1       1        1      7     50   kg   686   343
6   Myindicator          1       1        1      8     20   kg   686   343
7   Myindicator          1       2        4      9     50   kg   686   343
8   Myindicator          1       2        4      9     50   kg   686   343
9   Myindicator          1       2        4     10     40   kg   686   343
10  Myindicator          1       2        5     11     20   kg   686   343
11  Myindicator          1       2        5      3     40   kg   686   343
12  Myindicator          1       2        5      3     40   kg   686   343
13  Myindicator          1       2        6      2     10   kg   686   343
14  Myindicator          1       3        7     12     50   kg   686   343
15  Myindicator          1       3        7     12     50   kg   686   343
16  Myindicator          1       3        8     14     15   kg   686   343
17  Myindicator          1       3        8     14     15   kg   686   343
18  Myindicator          1       3        8     13     15   kg   686   343
19  Myindicator          1       3        8     13      1   kg   686   343
20  Myindicator          1       4        9     15     10   kg   686   343
21  Myindicator          1       4        9     16     10   kg   686   343
```

Indexes dropped:
None

Grouping on `['name', 'Continent']`
Grouped sums and cutoffs for this hierarchy:

```
           name  Continent  Region  Country  State  Value Unit  gsum  gmax
0   Myindicator          1       1        3      1     50   kg   686   343
1   Myindicator          1       1        3      4     50   kg   686   343
2   Myindicator          1       1        2      5     20   kg   686   343
3   Myindicator          1       1        2      5     50   kg   686   343
4   Myindicator          1       1        2      6     30   kg   686   343
5   Myindicator          1       1        1      7     50   kg   686   343
6   Myindicator          1       1        1      8     20   kg   686   343
7   Myindicator          1       2        4      9     50   kg   686   343
8   Myindicator          1       2        4      9     50   kg   686   343
9   Myindicator          1       2        4     10     40   kg   686   343
10  Myindicator          1       2        5     11     20   kg   686   343
11  Myindicator          1       2        5      3     40   kg   686   343
12  Myindicator          1       2        5      3     40   kg   686   343
13  Myindicator          1       2        6      2     10   kg   686   343
14  Myindicator          1       3        7     12     50   kg   686   343
15  Myindicator          1       3        7     12     50   kg   686   343
16  Myindicator          1       3        8     14     15   kg   686   343
17  Myindicator          1       3        8     14     15   kg   686   343
18  Myindicator          1       3        8     13     15   kg   686   343
19  Myindicator          1       3        8     13      1   kg   686   343
20  Myindicator          1       4        9     15     10   kg   686   343
21  Myindicator          1       4        9     16     10   kg   686   343
```

Indexes dropped:
None

Grouping on `['name', 'Continent', 'Region']`
Grouped sums and cutoffs for this hierarchy:

```
           name  Continent  Region  Country  State  Value Unit  gsum  gmax
0   Myindicator          1       1        3      1     50   kg   270   135
1   Myindicator          1       1        3      4     50   kg   270   135
2   Myindicator          1       1        2      5     20   kg   270   135
3   Myindicator          1       1        2      5     50   kg   270   135
4   Myindicator          1       1        2      6     30   kg   270   135
5   Myindicator          1       1        1      7     50   kg   270   135
6   Myindicator          1       1        1      8     20   kg   270   135
7   Myindicator          1       2        4      9     50   kg   250   135
8   Myindicator          1       2        4      9     50   kg   250   135
9   Myindicator          1       2        4     10     40   kg   250   135
10  Myindicator          1       2        5     11     20   kg   250   135
11  Myindicator          1       2        5      3     40   kg   250   135
12  Myindicator          1       2        5      3     40   kg   250   135
13  Myindicator          1       2        6      2     10   kg   250   135
14  Myindicator          1       3        7     12     50   kg   146   135
15  Myindicator          1       3        7     12     50   kg   146   135
16  Myindicator          1       3        8     14     15   kg   146   135
17  Myindicator          1       3        8     14     15   kg   146   135
18  Myindicator          1       3        8     13     15   kg   146   135
19  Myindicator          1       3        8     13      1   kg   146   135
20  Myindicator          1       4        9     15     10   kg    20   135 *
21  Myindicator          1       4        9     16     10   kg    20   135 *
```

Indexes dropped:
20,21

Grouping on `['name', 'Continent', 'Region', 'Country']`
Grouped sums and cutoffs for this hierarchy:

```
           name  Continent  Region  Country  State  Value Unit  gsum  gmax
0   Myindicator          1       1        3      1     50   kg   100    50
1   Myindicator          1       1        3      4     50   kg   100    50
2   Myindicator          1       1        2      5     20   kg   100    50
3   Myindicator          1       1        2      5     50   kg   100    50
4   Myindicator          1       1        2      6     30   kg   100    50
5   Myindicator          1       1        1      7     50   kg    70    50
6   Myindicator          1       1        1      8     20   kg    70    50
7   Myindicator          1       2        4      9     50   kg   140    70
8   Myindicator          1       2        4      9     50   kg   140    70
9   Myindicator          1       2        4     10     40   kg   140    70
10  Myindicator          1       2        5     11     20   kg   100    70
11  Myindicator          1       2        5      3     40   kg   100    70
12  Myindicator          1       2        5      3     40   kg   100    70
13  Myindicator          1       2        6      2     10   kg    10    70 *
14  Myindicator          1       3        7     12     50   kg   100    50
15  Myindicator          1       3        7     12     50   kg   100    50
16  Myindicator          1       3        8     14     15   kg    46    50 *
17  Myindicator          1       3        8     14     15   kg    46    50 *
18  Myindicator          1       3        8     13     15   kg    46    50 *
19  Myindicator          1       3        8     13      1   kg    46    50 *
```

Indexes dropped:
13,16,17,18,19

Grouping on `['name', 'Continent', 'Region', 'Country', 'State']`
Grouped sums and cutoffs for this hierarchy:

```
           name  Continent  Region  Country  State  Value Unit  gsum  gmax
0   Myindicator          1       1        3      1     50   kg    50    25
1   Myindicator          1       1        3      4     50   kg    50    25
2   Myindicator          1       1        2      5     20   kg    70    35
3   Myindicator          1       1        2      5     50   kg    70    35
4   Myindicator          1       1        2      6     30   kg    30    35 *
5   Myindicator          1       1        1      7     50   kg    50    25
6   Myindicator          1       1        1      8     20   kg    20    25 *
7   Myindicator          1       2        4      9     50   kg   100    50
8   Myindicator          1       2        4      9     50   kg   100    50
9   Myindicator          1       2        4     10     40   kg    40    50 *
10  Myindicator          1       2        5     11     20   kg    20    40 *
11  Myindicator          1       2        5      3     40   kg    80    40
12  Myindicator          1       2        5      3     40   kg    80    40
14  Myindicator          1       3        7     12     50   kg   100    50
15  Myindicator          1       3        7     12     50   kg   100    50
```

Indexes dropped:
4,6,9,10

Final table:

```
           name  Continent  Region  Country  State  Value Unit
0   Myindicator          1       1        3      1     50   kg
1   Myindicator          1       1        3      4     50   kg
2   Myindicator          1       1        2      5     20   kg
3   Myindicator          1       1        2      5     50   kg
5   Myindicator          1       1        1      7     50   kg
7   Myindicator          1       2        4      9     50   kg
8   Myindicator          1       2        4      9     50   kg
11  Myindicator          1       2        5      3     40   kg
12  Myindicator          1       2        5      3     40   kg
14  Myindicator          1       3        7     12     50   kg
15  Myindicator          1       3        7     12     50   kg
```

Comment: it returns this error `Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1`
I want to drop only the row where the sum is less than 1/30 the max of this groupby not all the df. This is to delete the rectancle that are 30x smaller than the max rectangle in a zoomable tree map that require a nested JSON. I hope that is more clear

Comment: At which line? This is why it would be useful to have an example of the data you are passing in as `df`.

Comment: It's the same think just keep in mind that I have different indicator, b, c, z, l and sL and they are hierarchically indicator >b>c>z>I>sL . I think I must use the index and delete from the df by index when the condition apply  but I can't get the index from the groupby

Comment: It can’t be the same thing if you are applying `sum` to it. Unless you are not actually grouping and are rather just using `groupby` to hide indexes from every row, which is somewhat unnecessary

Comment: I posted an example of the ungrouped df

Comment: And this is why I am asking for a copy of the original ungrouped dataframe, because my function below does remove rows from an ungrouped frame where the sum of the group is lower than 30x the max. So there must be something different about your dataframe than the one I mocked up myself

Comment: In your function you only do it for the whole list but for my case I need to do it for the different lists ('name'),('name','b'),('name','b','c') because my tree map is zoomable and I need to drop rectangle in each transition

Comment: For example If I have an indicator that is 30x smaller than the max indicator i drop it, and if I have a b that is 30x smaller than the max b in this indicator but only for this indicator I drop it

Comment: That is a grouping change, you can’t drop all the rows with < 30x the max for every combination of identifiers without regrouping, because that information isn’t in your grouped df.

Comment: I will try to iterate on rows of the ungrouped df

Comment: I’m sure there is a way to get from your starting dataframe to the one you want, but I don’t think it’s the way you’re trying to do it, and without a *comprehensive* example of your starting dataframe, and an indication of which rows you would expect to have left after running this function, it’s very difficult to help you achieve it. I’m happy to help you but I can’t do it without a clearer example

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I edited the post, I didn't post the exact df because it's French first and second because it's a confidential work. I think the structure is clear now, if the indicator of a region <30/the max indicator of the other region I drop this region, if it's the case for a city with drop only the city of the same county they must be different cities with same number in other coutries. Hope this is much clearer

Comment: `if it's the case for a city with drop only the city of the same county they must be different cities with same number in other coutries`  - I am still not clear what this means. Do you intend to loop through each hierarchical grouping and drop ANY that are less than 30x the sum of the grouping above?

Comment: Exactly, loop trough each hierarchical grouping and drop any that are less than 30X the sum of the grouping

Comment: Can you tell me which rows you would expect to be dropped from the example table I added to this answer if the cutoff was 2x instead of 30x.

Comment: drop the last row where region= 3 because the value of region 1 which equal 270 is the max for the grouping region/
drop the row 111 where country = 6 because its <1/2 the max of this grouping which is country=4 140/
drop the row 2 where state = 8 because 20 is < 1/2 50/
drop the row 4 where state = 6/
drop the row 8  where state=40/
drop the row 10 where state=11/

Comment: Ok I am not sure the process you explained before is what you actually want. I am going to edit this answer with a new function that loops through each hierarchical group and deletes rows that don't meet that groupings cutoff, and you can see for yourself the issue, and hopefully we can work out exactly what it is you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's exactly what I was looking for I mid the transform part.

Comment: There is still one point, it is for the max for example for the region 1 coutry 1 the max should be 50, and for the region 1 country 2 it should be 70. I should group the country of each region solo so I can do this

Comment: Can you explain why/what you mean? At which step are you saying there is a problem? This algorithm is always grouping by descending hierarchy. i.e. it groups by Region then *within* the regions it groups by Country.

Comment: Yes but when grouping by the whole list that contains the latest child which is boroughs here, the gorupby display all the boroughs of all the cities and all the countries and they have all the same max which I don't want I want the max for a boroughs to be calculated for the boroughs of the specified city not all the cities. Tell me if it's still unclear I can rewrite a complete example

Comment: Yes a more complete example would be helpful. It is sounding like it might just be that your max value needs to be calculated differently

Comment: Do you want that sort of `max` logic for every step or just the last one?

Comment: For every one please

Comment: Ok, try the latest edit. You can't do the max of the parent group for the first level grouping (i.e. `name`) because that is just the same as the max for the grouping.

Comment: It seem to be work but I get an error at the end it includ gsum on the grouping I didn't identify why `Grouping on ['nom', 'batiment', 'contributeur', 'zone', 'lot', 'sous_lot', 'gsum']`

Comment: That was due to the way `pandas.DataFrame` objects are passed around. A bit like python dicts when you pass it to a function the function operates on the original dataframe. I have changed the function to use a copy now.  Drop the 'gsum' column from your starting dataframe if it is present and try again with the new function. You will need to assign the output of `drop_small()` to a variable in order to keep the output now